# Homeomorphism preserving partitions

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic topological spaces.

Consider a equivalent relation $R_X$ and $R_Y$ that partition $X$ into  $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ of and $Y$ into $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ respectively.

$X_i$ is homeomorphic to $Y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

The quotient topologies $X/R_X$ and $Y/R_Y$ are homeomorphic.

Does there exist a homeomorphism $H$ such that $H(X_i) = Y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$?

If not, what it we have the information that the homeomorphism of $X/R_X$ and $Y/R_Y$ maps $X_i/R_X$ to $Y_i/R_Y$?

If not, is it true on some special topological spaces? (I'm interested when $X$ and $Y$ are spheres with boundaries, the partitions are simply connected regions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s certainly not true in general.

Let $X=Y=[0,2)$, $X_1=Y_2=[0,1)$, and $X_2=Y_1=[1,2)$. There is no homeomorphism of $[0,2)$ onto itself that interchanges $[0,1)$ and $[1,2)$.

It will be true if the partitions are clopen partitions.

**Added:** A stronger example: $X=Y=[0,2)\cup[3,4]\cup[5,6]$, $X_1=Y_2=[0,1)\cup[3,4]$, and $X_2=Y_1=[1,2)\cup[5,6]$. Now the map $H:X\to Y$ that is the identity on $[0,2)$ and interchanges $[3,4]$ and $[5,6]$ in the obvious way is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto $Y$ such that there are $x_1\in X_1$ and $x_2\in X_2$ such that $H(x_i)\in Y_i$ for $i=1,2$, but there is no homeomorphism of $X$ onto $Y$ that interchanges $[0,1)\cup[3,4]$ and $[1,2)\cup[5.6]$.

Comment: What if I make sure the there is a homeomorphism, such that for every $i$, there exist a point $x\in X_i$ and $y\in Y_i$, such that $H(x) = y$?

Comment: @ChaoXu: That’s not enough. Let $X=Y=[0,2)\cup [3,4]\cup[5,6]$, $X_1=[0,1)\cup[3,4]=Y_2$, and $X_2=[1,2)\cup[5,6]=Y_1$. The map from $X$ to $Y$ that interchanges $[3,4]$ and $[5,6]$ meets your requirement, but there’s still no homeomorphism that interchanges $X_1$ and $Y_1$.